# I'm making a makefile that exits if there isn't a proper exit status from the python code

Tags: shell, makefile

```
cmd=python sol.py
A:
        @$(cmd)
.PHONY: disp
disp:
        python sol.py
        EXIT_STAtus=$$? \
        ifeq ($EXIT_STAtus,1) \
                @echo "GG"; \
                exit 1; \
        else \
                @echo "ALL GOOD"; \
        endif
```

I have made a `makefile` of such kind, the `if` loop and the exit all works fine, but the echoing is not happening in either parts.
Can you please tell why?

Comment: Maybe you want a linebreak after assigning to EXIT_STATUS?

Comment: On which operating system? what is your shell? `ifeq` is *not* a standard shell construct.

Comment: The default behavior of Make is to abort if something fails. Just remove the rest (it's broken in too many ways to pick apart anyway. For a start, you can't use Make `ifeq` to interact with run-time results, because these things are evaluated before any recipe runs).

Comment: @shellter GNU Make accepts a number of standard filenames, including this.

Comment: Tangentially, masking all your commands with `@` is a horrible antipattern. There is a reason `make` tells you what it's doing - take them out so you can see what you are doing (then optionally use `make -s` to make it less verbose, once you have debugged it properly). *Maybe* selectively add it back to *absolutely* trivial things like unconditional debug prints if you have a big build.

Comment: It's not true that make programs only read `Makefile` files.  GNU make will look for the files `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile` in that order and parse the first one that it finds.  Or you can use `-f` to tell it to read a different makefile.

Comment: There's a nice trick for handling echoing of command lines described here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Comment: Thanks for the correction on GNUmake and that `makefile`, `GNUmakeile` and `Makefile` are all valid default names. My experience was with Solaris. I've removed my initial comment. Good luck to all.

Comment: Actually, the question is unclear, since the code is not really an [MCVE]

Answer (score 3):

You are confused and misunderstand `make` so spend several hours reading the [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), and also the documentation of your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), probably [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). Please understand what happens at `make` time and what happens inside `make` recipes (the actions are interpreted by your shell, not by `make`; that shell is *run* by  `make`).

`ifeq` is a rarely useful [conditional `make` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html), acting at "parsing" time (when the `make` program is reading your `Makefile`). It is somehow analog to `#if` in C code, in the sense that it asks `make` to *skip* some input. You should not use `ifeq` in your case, or when you want to change behavior at run time (of `make`).

You probably need a conditional shell command. Read about [conditional shell constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) in `bash` (they use `if`, a shell keyword). Read also documentation of [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html), often abbreviated as `[` in shell commands, and notice that it is also a bash [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

As [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) comments, you don't even need any conditional shell command in your case. I think that error messages should be output by your Python script, and they should be relevant (so you'll better improve your `sol.py`  script instead).

In your `Makefile`, it should be a single command, because different shell commands in your `Makefile` don't communicate and are run independently by `make`. Read the [using one shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) section of `make` documentation.

I am guessing that you might want to

```
disp:
        python sol.py; \
        EXIT_STAtus=$$? ; \
        if [ "$$EXIT_STAtus" -eq 1 ]; then \
                echo "GG"; \
                exit 1; \
        else \
                echo "ALL GOOD"; \
        endif
```

Notice that you execute a *single* shell command (from `python` to `endif` above), so you need backslashes at end of every line except the last.

You might want to run `make --trace` (and/or `make -n`) or even [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` to understand what is happening and to debug your `Makefile`.

You definitely should spend more time in reading the documentation.

BTW, why don't you change instead your `sol.py` Python script to output `GG` or `ALL GOOD`? It might be a simpler solution, and I actually recommend doing that and have a `bettersol.py` Python script. Then your `Makefile` rule should be much simpler:

```
disp:
        python bettersol.py
```

Also, when debugging a `Makefile`, you should first remove all `@` to understand what is happening.

As a rule of thumb, avoid using `@` in `Makefile`s. In general, **`make` should run verbosely**. As a beginner, you should never use `@`. Later you might *sometimes* add `@` in very *few* rules (but I don't recommend doing that).

NB: Your first `make` rule for `A:` is also very bad (or at least ugly and smells bad). You probably should at least remove the `@`, and if `A` is an output of `sol.py` you'll better improve `sol.py` to make that *explicit*, perhaps having `python sol.py > $@` in your first recipe.

Comment: The *purpose* of the shell's `if` and related conditionals is to run a command and examine its output status. You should almost never need to directly examine the value of `$?` in a conditional. You want `if sol.py; then echo Good things; else echo bad things; fi` or in this trivial case perhaps just `sol.py && echo Good things || { echo Bad things; exit 1; }` ... but just the error message from Make is probably sufficient to see that something went wrong, so `sol.py && echo Good things` may well suffice.

Comment: ... Or in a Makefile, simply `sol.py` and then as the next line of the recipe in a separate shell, `echo Good things`. The `echo` will only happen if `make` didn't exit because of an error at the previous step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your answer is wrong. The right answer was that make throws an error as soon as the code was run, so the control will never go to the echo statements.

Comment: Your question was also wrong. So I gave a probably correct answer to a wrong, and unclear, question. My feeling is that you are using `make` in a way it is not intended for.